# Pasar de una ventana a otra en react native y firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

Mi pregunta es como pasar si mi formulario es verdadero con un if 
este es mi codigo

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
if (user != null) {
console.log(user)
}
})
}

signUpUser = (email, password) => {
try {
 if (this.state.password.length < 6) {
 alert("Please enter atleast 6 characters")
 return;
}
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
 }
catch (error) {
 console.log(error.toString())
}
}

loginUser = (email, password) => {
try {

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user) {
console.log(user)
})
}
catch (error) {
 console.log(error.toString())
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz uso de [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), una vez el screen haga parte del stack de navegacion, solo tiene que acceder mediante los props y hacer uso de la función navigate para ir a la pantalla que desee, un pequeño ejemplo:

```
   //Creas tu stack de navegacion:
        import {
          StackNavigator,
        } from 'react-navigation';

        const App = StackNavigator({
          Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
//La llave del objeto es el identificador del screen y lo vas a usar en el navigation.
          Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
        });
```

y en el screen en donde haces la validacion, solo llamas a this.props.navigation y despues la funcion navigation, ejemplo:

```
     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          <Button
            title="Go to Jane's profile"
            onPress={() =>
//El primer parametro indica el identificador de la pantalla a la que quieres ir.
              navigate('Profile')
            }
```